# Mouse click in non-item area of CListBox

Tags: mfc, clistbox

I want to know when the user has clicked in a CListBox, but outside of any item. I was hoping to get some notification in the containing dialog so I can process the point to determine if it is inside an item via `mylistbox.ItemFromPoint(flags,outside)`. But clicks within the listbox don't seem to result in such events. What event should I be looking for in the parent dialog, and what needs to be set up to enable it? I really don't care if it is a click or just mousedown.

My purpose for this is to deselect all items if the user clicks outside of any item, with `mylistbox.SetCurSel(-1)`.

---

**Addendum:** This is the full code for the class implemented as suggested by @mercurydime.

**(Header)**

```
#ifndef INCLUDE_CMYLISTBOX_H
#define INCLUDE_CMYLISTBOX_H

class CMyListBox : public CListBox
{
public:

    CMyListBox();

    void                allow_deselect( bool allow = true );

protected:

    bool                m_allow_deselect;

    afx_msg void        OnLButtonDown( UINT flags, CPoint point );

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

#endif  //  INCLUDE_CMYLISTBOX_H
```

**(Body)**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CMyListBox.h"

CMyListBox::CMyListBox()
    : CListBox(), m_allow_deselect( false )
{
}

void CMyListBox::allow_deselect( bool allow )
{
    m_allow_deselect = allow;
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP( CMyListBox, CListBox )
    ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CMyListBox::OnLButtonDown( UINT flags, CPoint point )
{
    if( m_allow_deselect )
    {
        BOOL outside( TRUE );
        ItemFromPoint( point, outside );

        if( outside )
            SetCurSel( -1 );
    }

    CListBox::OnLButtonDown( flags, point );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use the **Class Wizard** to create a class derived from `CListBox`:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
- Click the down arrow on the **Add Class** button
- Select the **MFC Class** menu item
- Make sure the base class is set to `CListBox`

2. Add a message handler for `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
- Click the **Messages** tab
- Double-click `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`

3. Add your `ItemFromPoint` code inside the handler

```
void CMyListBox::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    BOOL bOutside = TRUE;
    UINT uItem = ItemFromPoint(point, bOutside);

    if (bOutside)
    {
        // do whatever
    }

    CListBox::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
}
```

Comment: Okay, I'll accept this approach. I was hoping to do it from the parent without subclassing the control, but since I'm already subclassing CStatic and CComboBox, why not? This will let me make other tweaks later on as well. +1 for the suggestion.

Comment: I added the full code for the implemented class to my original question. Thanks again.